# Count a specific character in text - pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark data frame which contains a text column. This column can have text (string) information in it. All I want to do is count A, B, C, D etc in each row of this column. It is like:

```
df = spark.read.csv('Data.csv', header=True)
df.select(['text']).show(truncate = False)
+-------------------------+
|text                     |
+-------------------------+
|BBEBEBEFC                |
|DDBBCDCBBECCBBE          |
|DCDBBEDBBE               |
+-------------------------+
```

Now I Want to count number of B, C , D etc in each column and create respective columns like

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|text                     | B | C | D | E | F |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|BBEBEBEFC                | 4 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 
|DDBBCDCBBECCBBE          | 6 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In pandas, it can be simply done by:

```
df['A'] = df['text'].str.count('A')
...
```

I want to perform same thing in Pyspark without loops (data is huge). If someone could suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: Now that the pandas_api is available, you can do it the way you would in Pandas, too.
df = df.pandas_api()
df['A'] = df['text'].str.count('A')
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split, explode, group by, pivot, count:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = (df.withColumn('miid', F.monotonically_increasing_id().alias('miid'))
         .withColumn('split_text', F.explode(F.split('text', '')))
         .filter("split_text != ''")
         .groupBy('text', 'miid')
         .pivot('split_text')
         .agg(F.count('*'))
         .fillna(0)
         .drop('miid')
      )

df2.show()
+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|           text|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|
+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|DDBBCDCBBECCBBE|  6|  4|  3|  2|  0|
|     DCDBBEDBBE|  4|  1|  3|  2|  0|
|      BBEBEBEFC|  4|  1|  0|  3|  1|
+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @mck, It is working. But I am getting some weird results at some places like: for `text =CCAECDDFFDEEFCFFEFFEFBE`  : I am getting `A =635, B =635, C=2540, D=1905, E=3810, F=5080`

Comment: @SurenderSingh you can try the modified answer which adds an index column to address cases with duplicate text

Comment: thanks. This is working fine, Although I was wondering why the other columns(apart from text) of the dataframe are not going in df2

Comment: @SurenderSingh if you want other columns, you can group by `(*df.columns, 'miid')`